# If Statement in Table valued Function

Tags: sql-server, user-defined-functions

I have 2 table-valued function that are very similar, the only difference is that I need one additional `Max()` call on the second one.  I want to consolidate these into one but I can't quite figure out how to do it.

First Function

```
ALTER FUNCTION [DayTrade].[udf_GetTotalLast90Days] 
(   
    @Date       datetime
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    SELECT    Acct, Sum(AGGCnt) As AGGCnt, AGGNumb
    FROM      DT.vwGet_CountHist
    WHERE   (PostDate >= @Date - 90) AND (PostDate <= @Date)
    GROUP BY Acct, AGGNumb
)
```

Second Function

```
ALTER FUNCTION [DayTrade].[udf_GetTotalLast90Days] 
(   
    @Date       datetime
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    SELECT     Acct, Sum(AGGCnt) As AGGCnt, Max(AGGNumb) As AGGNumb
    FROM      DT.vwGet_CountHist
    WHERE   (PostDate >= @Date - 90) AND (PostDate <= @Date)
    GROUP BY Acct
)
```

As you can see the difference in the second one is I am adding the `Max(AGGNumb) As AGGNumb` and removing one of the Group Bys.  I attempted to change this and pass in a additional variable @Agg that was a bit field to then use an `IF statement` to choose which function to use but I couldn't get it to work.

Any suggestions about how to consolidate these two functions into 1?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One parameter will be NULL, so the WHERE fails for one clause only.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [DayTrade].[udf_GetTotalLast90Days] 
(   
    @Date       datetime = NULL,
    @BusinessDate = NULL
)
RETURNS TABLE  AS RETURN  
(
    SELECT    Acct, Sum(AGGCnt) As AGGCnt, AGGNumb
    FROM      DT.vwGet_CountHist
    WHERE   (PostDate >= @Date - 90) AND (PostDate <= @Date)
    GROUP BY Acct, AGGNumb
    UNION ALL
    SELECT     Acct, Sum(AGGCnt) As AGGCnt, Max(AGGNumb) As AGGNumb
    FROM      DT.vwGet_CountHist
    WHERE   (PostDate >= @BusinessDate - 90) AND (PostDate <= @BusinessDate)
    GROUP BY Acct
)
```

Comment: I updated the code above, it is @Date on both where clauses not @businessDate, does that make a difference?

Comment: @bluefeet: you still need a control variable to decide which query to run. You may as well as have 2 parameters to control this

Comment: I guess I am still confused by this.  It is one parameter @Date, then I know I should add a second parameter to tell the function which select statement to use, but when I try to do that I run into trouble.

Comment: I was using something called @Max and then an If statement to say - if @Max = true, then use the query with the Max(), if it was false, use the other one. Something similar to what can be used in a stored proc.  These table valued functions are new to me and I can't seem to figure out how to get it to decide which query to run.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass a control parameter to the function like so (untested)

EDIT: added nested SELECT

```
ALTER FUNCTION [DayTrade].[udf_GetTotalLast90Days]  
    (        @Date       datetime, @GetMax tinyint ) 
    RETURNS TABLE  AS RETURN  
    (     SELECT     Acct, Sum(AGGCnt) As AGGCnt, 
    CASE @GetMax = 1 THEN (SELECT Max(AGGNumb) FROM DT.vwGet_CountList WHERE (...)GROUP BY Max(aGGNumb)) 
ELSE (SELECT AGGNumb FROM DT.vwGet_CountList WHERE (...)) AS AGGNum  END 
        FROM      DT.vwGet_CountHist     
        WHERE   (PostDate >= @BusinessDate - 90) AND (PostDate <= @BusinessDate)     
        GROUP BY Acct )
```

If that doesnt work, then you may need to implement the two SELECTs separately, but in the same Procedure - i know doesnt really solve the problem but it will only require 1 procedure.

Comment: Doing it that way, I get an error about not having the AGGNumb in the Group By.  I only need it in the Group By when I am not using the Max().

Comment: Its not the most efficient way using nested select

Comment: That is what I was trying to do, was implement them both in the same function but I couldn't figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I think, this should work:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [DayTrade].[udf_GetTotalLast90Days] 
(   
    @Date       datetime,
    @Agg        bit
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    SELECT    Acct, Sum(AGGCnt) As AGGCnt, MAX(AGGNumb) AS AGGNumb
    FROM      DT.vwGet_CountHist
    WHERE   (PostDate >= @Date - 90) AND (PostDate <= @Date)
    GROUP BY Acct, AGGNumb * (1 - @Agg)
)
```

When `@Agg = 1`, it will group by `Acct` only, when `@Agg = 0`, then by `Acct, AGGNumb`.